# Can't convert from model to path.model C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to do my first API with ASP.NET Core 6 and Entity Framework Core.

Basically I have a model class:

```
namespace SistemaDeTarefas.Models
{
    public class UsuarioModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Nome { get; set; }

        public string? Email { get; set;}
    }
}
```

An interface

```
using SistemaDeTarefas.Models;

namespace SistemaDeTarefas.Repositorios.Interfaces
{
    public interface IUsuarioRepositorio
    {
        Task<List<UsuarioModel>> BuscarTodosUsuarios();
        Task<UsuarioModel> BuscarId(int id);
        Task<UsuarioModel> Adicionar(UsuarioModel Usuario);
        Task<UsuarioModel> Atualizar(UsuarioModel Usuario, int id);
        Task<bool> Apagar(int id);
    }
}
```

And a repository

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SistemaDeTarefas.Data;
using SistemaDeTarefas.Models;
using SistemaDeTarefas.Repositorios.Interfaces;

namespace SistemaDeTarefas.Repositorios
{
    public class UsuarioRepositorio : IUsuarioRepositorio
    {
        private readonly SistemaTarefasDBContext _dbContext;

        public UsuarioRepositorio(SistemaTarefasDBContext sistemaTarefasDbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = sistemaTarefasDbContext;
        }

        public async Task<UsuarioModel> Adicionar(UsuarioModel usuario)
        {
            return await _dbContext.Usuarios.Add(usuario);
        }

        public Task<bool> Apagar(int id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Task<UsuarioModel> Atualizar(UsuarioModel Usuario, int id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public async Task<UsuarioModel> BuscarId(int id)
        {
            return await _dbContext.Usuarios.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
        }

        public async Task<List<UsuarioModel>> BuscarTodosUsuarios()
        {
           return await _dbContext.Usuarios.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

In both methods `Adicionar()` and `BUscarTodosUsuarios()`, the return gets highlighted and Visual Studio warns

> Can't convert from SistemaDeTarefas.Models.UsuarioModel to UsuarioModel

That makes no sense, since it's like it can't convert from model to path.model

I was trying to implement methods for this entity crud, but then I get the error described

Comment: Do you have 2 classes called `UsuarioModel`?

Comment: Nope, only this one

Comment: Please check closely, that is the only reason you can get this error.

Comment: If you used EF to scafold a database then it would have created an entity definition. The easiest way to find it is to go to your DbContext.Usarious, which will be a `DbSet<Usario>`, *not* a `DbSet<UsarioModel>`.  If it does happen to be a UsarioModel, right-click on the UsarioModel inside the arrow brackets and Go to Definition. It will take you to a different class than the SistemaDeTarefas.Models.UsuarioModel.

Comment: Side note: another tip, remove this repository layer from your application. As you see it does nothing but wrapping a DbSet. It's totally redundant.

Comment: Guys, i hadn't even check my DbContext, was lacking the "Using SIstemaDeTarafes.Models", by adding it the problem has been solved